# Android Studio vs russian language

Tags: android, sqlite, encoding, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have Android Studio and Eclipse. If I compile code in Eclipse there are no problems with russian symbols in code, but in Android Studio I faced with that problem "СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅ".
Furthemore, it doesn't depends on how it looks in Studio - this "СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅ" occur on device.
Example of code:

```
db.execSQL("Insert into type(name,image) values('Медведь',null);");
        db.execSQL("Insert into type(name,image) values('Водка',null);");
        db.execSQL("Insert into type(name,image) values('Балалайка',null);");
        db.execSQL("Insert into type(name,image) values('Привет',null);");
```

Can anybody help me?
Android Studio is really nice to work and I don't want to go back to eclipse.

Comment: this is because of font not available.so if you change this into utf-8, utf-16,iso-8859-1 etc font so it will support wide area of character-set,in android studio also you can set this as by selecting File encoding that you can find in File Menu or just select the file where you are writting this and choose your encoding type or you can set for whole project or as default setting by selecting the file  setting or Default settings in other settings and you are.